# When I move or delete files, they occasionally appear right back where they were a day later

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, file-management

When I move or delete files, they occasionally appear right back where they were a day later. Also, when I move files, they not only re-appear where I moved them from, they are also where I moved them to as well. Is my system duplicating files? It seems so.

This problem has been occurring randomly, but with increasing regularity. Most of the issues are with downloaded music and image files, but it has happened occasionally with Word documents as well.

Also, some of my desktop icons have reappeared after I have moved or deleted them. I have run extensive system scans for malware, viruses and the sort but nothing pops up.

Is there something wrong with my settings or is there another problem? I use Windows 7, SP 1 with all current updates, and have a few other issues. I was worried that perhaps some of my settings were incorrect.

What is this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Your malware scanner is broken. It should show Windows 7.

Comment: What security or backup software do you have installed?

Comment: Is your PC part of a Windows domain?

Comment: I use AVG 2012 Free, Spybot Search and Destroy, Glary's Utilities and PC Tools AntiVirus Free. Generally the free stuff is all I have. For backup however, I use a Seagate. My laptop is not a part of a domain.

Comment: My guess is one of the tools is rolling back changes.

Comment: And keeping the new changes as well? That is weird. How can I fix this if I don't know what tool is doing it? It has to be AVG, Spybot or Glarys, PC Tools is a new one and it happened way before I started using it.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely answer is that you are joined to a domain and your roaming account is not properly syncronising back with the server. This means that when you re-login your deleted files are being restored from your roaming account.

If you're not on a windows domain, you may have some malfunctioning backup software which could cause a similar issue.